# What SQL type is used in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

This is my first post in here, 
I am new to SQL and I started learning it, I use it mainly in excel to get data from an outer Database
I first go to data then Refresh all then from the menu I choose connection properties
Then  a dialogue appears and I input my code in the window called Command text from the Tab Definition

I added images to show where I input my SQL code

My question is what type of SQL do I input there ?
is it **mySQL** or **SQLServer** or **what** ??, so I can learn it, because some commands just don't work with me the way they are supposed to do

[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Comment: i would say probably sql server. i use use sql server to input data to excel through power pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to any database type as long as you have the appropriate [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) drivers.  For example, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/) is documentation for *MySQL for Excel*.  Quote from article "[Use Microsoft Query to retrieve external data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e)":

> If the external database that you want to access is not supported by the
>   ODBC drivers that are installed with Microsoft Query, then you
>   need to obtain and install a Microsoft Office-compatible ODBC driver
>   from a third-party vendor, such as the manufacturer of the database.
>   Contact the database vendor for installation instructions.
>
> OLAP databases do not require ODBC drivers. When you install Microsoft Query, drivers are installed for databases that were created
>   by using Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services. To connect to other
>   OLAP databases, you need to install a data source driver and client
>   software.

Whichever database type you connect to, you will still be using Microsoft's SQL variant (as developed for SQL Server).  As a beginner you're not going to notice too many differences right off the top.  Most of the differences are related to data types, such as `DATE` vs `DATETIME`.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance) is a wiki on SQL Compliance and [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Access-SQL-d5f21d10-cd73-4507-925e-bb26e377fe7e?CorrelationId=9f4e58cb-e43c-4c46-ab6c-cf27ea8c6b9c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010341468) article on MS Access SQL will also apply to Excel Query.

Comment: I think you are correct, Yes it is SQL Server
but I still see some variations, for example when I use an alias for column name I should need to add [ ] around my alias, but when I do I get an error
instead when I remove the [ ] it works fine

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to many data source including: SQL Server database, Access database, MySQL database, PostgreSQL database etc..

You can find the full list here: [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-external-data-sources-Power-Query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)